# Nginx location blocks for three different projects

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm having troubles trying to set up location blocks in Nginx. I have three projects/directories in my server that I want to serve under the same domain. Two react ones and one nodeJS server.

What I want to achieve is:

1. If going to the domain root, I want to serve one of the React apps. So this is just static files since the project is built. (This is working fine)
2. If going to `/check` I want this to be passed to the nodeJS application (this is working fine too)
3. Here comes the tricky part. I want everything else, that is not `/check` or the root domain, to load the other React app. (this is not working)

This is what I currently have:

```
server {

        root /var/www/landing/public;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /(?<something>.*)/ {
           alias /var/www/react-frontend/build/;
           index index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /check/ {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
        }
}
```

Hopefully I was able to explain everything clearly.
Thanks.

Comment: You really need to be using different hostnames for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael. there is no way to achieve this kind of routing under the same domain?? :(

Comment: Try `location ~ ^/(?!(check))` and add your proxy directives

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand... the /check one is working fine

Comment: It's a negative regex match, everything that _isn't_ `check` should read that location block

Comment: I understand! I've tried but I got a too many redirects error: https://puu.sh/Ed1TV/e184d17a05.png
either by going to the root or to a subpath :/

Comment: Use the `=` indicator for the other locations, like `location = / {` and `location = /check/ {`

Answer (score 3):

Here are example configuration.

```
server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:8088;
  location / {
    content_by_lua_block {
        ngx.say("root")
        ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_OK)
    }
  }
  location ~* "^\/check(.*)$" {
    content_by_lua_block {
        ngx.say("check")
        ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_OK)
    }
  }
  location ~* "^\/(.*)\/+(.*)$" {
    content_by_lua_block {
        ngx.say("all other")
        ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_OK)
    }
  }
}
```

And here are tests:

```
# curl 127.0.0.1:8088
root
# curl 127.0.0.1:8088/
root
# curl 127.0.0.1:8088/ll
root
# curl 127.0.0.1:8088/ll/
all other
# curl 127.0.0.1:8088/check
check
# curl 127.0.0.1:8088/check/
check
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do something like this:

```
location = / {
 index block
}

location = /check/ {
 check block }

location ~* ".*" {
 all others block
}
```

as the exact matches take precedence over the regexp match. Does that work for you?